# How can I add name node in my firebase database into listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database image
[image]

I am trying to add name node to a listview, how can I add a single firebase node into listview? I tried several things but unable to do it. My catlog say

> "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
>   com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference"

Please anyone tell me how to do this I am new in firebase.

```
public class Technician extends Activity {
private FirebaseDatabase database;

ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> tecnames = new ArrayList<>();
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_technician);

    ImageButton Back_Btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
    Back_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Technician.this, Technician_main.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("user");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String value = childSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tecnames.add(value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(Technician.this, Book_Now.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Technician.CostumAdapter costumAdapter = new Technician.CostumAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(costumAdapter);

}

private class CostumAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tecnames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cuctom_listview, null);

        TextView txt_one = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.skill_txt);
        txt_one.setText(tecnames.get(i));
        return view;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, change this line of code:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("user");
```

with

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("user");
```

You are getting `null` because you didn't instantiate your reference.

Comment: i am still getting null value

Comment: Have you set the permissions correctly in your Firebase Console?

Comment: u means rules {
"rules": {
  "user": {
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
     }
   }
 }
}

Comment: Try only to set them to true, for testing purposes. Does it work?

Comment: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String this is the error i am receiving

Comment: This means that you have now a connection to your database. Your `DatabaseReference` object is not `null` anymore. So the nullity problem is solved. There are many reasons that can generate such an error. I suppose you are pointing the an incorrect location in your database tree. But this is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: So, if you think that my answer helped you for solving the nullity problem, please consider accepting it. Thanks!